# rand() shuffle xml output

Tags: php, xml, random, shuffle

I created a XML file with a number of items like the example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>http://www.example.com/index.php?pagina=video-categories</id>
  <title><![CDATA[Example.com Categories RSS]]></title>
  <author>
  <name>Example.com</name>
  <email>email@example.com</email>
  </author>
  <updated></updated>
  <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/categories"/>
  <subtitle><![CDATA[HQ example videos in any category]]></subtitle>
  <rights>Copyrights reserved. Feel free to use the embed function.</rights>
    <item>
    <categoryname><![CDATA[100 Latest Videos]]></categoryname>
    <shortcategoryname><![CDATA[100 New Sex Clips]]></shortcategoryname>
    <categoryurl>http://www.example.com/1.html</categoryurl>
    <categoryimage>http://www.example.com/12347.jpg</categoryimage>
    </item>
    <item>
    <categoryname><![CDATA[100 Latest Videos]]></categoryname>
    <shortcategoryname><![CDATA[100 New Sex Clips]]></shortcategoryname>
    <categoryurl>http://www.example.com/2.html</categoryurl>
    <categoryimage>http://www.example.com/12346.jpg</categoryimage>
    </item>
    <item>
    <categoryname><![CDATA[100 Latest Videos]]></categoryname>
    <shortcategoryname><![CDATA[100 New Sex Clips]]></shortcategoryname>
    <categoryurl>http://www.example.com/3.html</categoryurl>
    <categoryimage>http://www.example.com/12345.jpg</categoryimage>
    </item>
    ... and more items ...
    </feed>
```

I have the following code with as output all links from the XML file

```
     <?php
     $html = ""; // var full of emptyness
     $url = "http://www.example.com/categories.xml";
     $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
     for($i = 0; $i < 35; $i++){ // Number of category here, I use a lower number at this moment... 
     $categoryname = $xml->item[$i]->categoryname;
     $shortcategoryname = $xml->item[$i]->shortcategoryname;
     $categoryurl = $xml->item[$i]->categoryurl;
     $html .= '<a class="purplewidebutton" href="' . $categoryurl . '" title="' . $categoryname . '">' . $shortcategoryname . '</a>';
     }
     echo $html;
     ?>
```

I'd like to show only 6 links and make their position radom from the XML feed. I'd like to have random links from the xml items. what should I add or change and should I use `rand()` or `shuffle()` to echo the 6 random links?

The php code is what I'm using at this moment to echo some links but it's not random...

Comment: What is the PHP that you have?

Comment: I use the displayed php code in my question but the xml file url is just an example url, not the real url..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't scroll.

Comment: I changed the question to make it more readable, I'm sorry for not adding the php to it's own code block but it's readable without scrolling after edit, thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$xml->item` is an array, so `shuffle` it and then get the first `6`, something like:

```
shuffle($xml->item);

foreach(array_slice($xml->item, 0, 6) as $item) {
    $categoryname = $item->categoryname;
    $shortcategoryname = $item->shortcategoryname;
    $categoryurl = $item->categoryurl;
    $html .= '<a class="purplewidebutton" href="' . $categoryurl . '" title="' . $categoryname . '">' . $shortcategoryname . '</a>';
}
echo $html;
```

Or with current code you could store the HTML in an array in the loop:

```
$html[] = '<a class="purplewidebutton" href="' . $categoryurl . '" title="' . $categoryname . '">' . $shortcategoryname . '</a>';
```

And after the loop:

```
shuffle($html);
echo implode("\n", array_slice($html, 0, 6));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working just great, I'll use the 2nd option in your answer, thanks again for your answer!

Comment: `foreach` would be easier and more versatile, like if you add items to the XML you won't need to change the loop.

Comment: Code I use: `<?php
$html = "";
$url = "categories.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
for($i = 0; $i < 35; $i++){
$categoryname = $xml->item[$i]->categoryname;
$shortcategoryname = $xml->item[$i]->shortcategoryname;
$categoryurl = $xml->item[$i]->categoryurl;

$html[] = '<a class="purplewidebutton" href="' . $categoryurl . '" title="' . $categoryname . '">' . $shortcategoryname . '</a>';
}
shuffle($html);
echo implode("\n", array_slice($html, 0, 6));
?>` I only need to change the 35 number if I remove/add categories to the xml feed, on pages I use cache so I run it only 4 times a page/day

Comment: @AbraCadaver This is great.  I've use a `for` loop initially too as I have heard it is faster.  Is there a way to do this with `for` instead of `foreach`?